# How to keep the default sink in PulseAudio when adding a new one?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm creating a sink like that:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=DummyPulseDeviceSink
```

The problem is that it immediately becomes the default one.

How to avoid that?

For now I'm using a workaround with remembering the current default with `pacmd info | sed -nre 's/Default sink name:\s*(.*)/\1/p'` and then restoring it.

Answer (score 0):

for pulseaudo as im usermode

cp /etc/pulse/default.pa $HOME/.config/pulse/default.pa

It could be you have to create the folder first in your home. I prefer to make changes if possible in my home.

Search for string `#set-default-sink` remove the comment and write your the default sink you wish behind.

for pulseaudio in systemmode you make the change directly in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

Comment: default.pa is read on startup. So it won't affect anything that happens afterwards. Like in this case when a new device is added at runtime.

Comment: what Version of ubuntu , please?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Comment: I'am sorry, i can not confirm this on my bionic. one last idea. which pulseaudio? Normal ubuntu package or snap?

Comment: A normal deb package, version 11.1-1ubuntu7.2. So you're saying that on your system executing `pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=DummyPulseDeviceSink; pacmd info | sed -nre 's/Default sink name:\s*(.*)/\1/p'` doesn't give the 'DummyPulseDeviceSink' as output?

Comment: meanwhile i get 3 of this dummy-devices. but my default is what I wrote in my config. equal  i restart pulseaudio or not. Out of knowledge.